# Algorithm domination

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

Studying for a test and getting this question:

```
Comparing two algorithms with asymptotic complexities O(n) and O(n + log(n)), 
which one of the following is true?

A) O(n + log(n)) dominates O(n)
B) O(n) dominates O(n + log(n))
C) Neither algorithm dominates the other.
```

O(n) dominates log(n) correct? So in this do we just take o(n) from both and deduce neither dominate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.  If runtime is the sum of several runtimes, by order of magnitude, the largest order of magnitude dominates.

Answer (score 3):

[C] is true, because of [the summation property](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/big-o/info) of *Big-O*

```
Summation 
O(f(n)) + O(g(n)) -> O(max(f(n), g(n))) 
For example: O(n^2) + O(n) = O(n^2)
```

In *Big-O*, you only care about the largest-growing function and ignore all the other additives.

Edit: originally I put [A] as an answer, I just didn't put much attention to all the options and misinterpreted the [A] option. Here is more formal proof

```
O(n) ~ O(n + log(n))      <=>
O(n) ~ O(n) + O(log(n))   <=>
O(n) ~ O(n).
```

Comment: C is true because if the very reason you stated

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that big-O notation is used in the sense of `asymptotic tight bound`, which really should be denoted with a big-Theta, then I would answer C), because `Theta(n) = Theta(n + log(n))`. (Because `log(n)` is dominated by `n`).

If I am formally (mathematically) correct, then I would say that none of these answers is correct, because `O(n)` and `O(n+log(n))` only give upper bounds, but not lower bounds on the asymptotic behaviour:

Let `f(n) in O(n)` and `g(n) in O(n + log(n))`. Then there are the following contra examples:

For A): Let `f(n) = n` in `O(n)` and `g(n) = 1` in `O(n + log(n))`. Then `g(n)` does not dominate `f(n)`.

for B): Let `f(n) = 1` in `O(n)` and `g(n) = n` in `O(n + log(n))`. Then `f(n)` does not dominate `g(n)`.

for C): Let `f(n) = 1` in `O(n)` and `g(n) = n` in `O(n + log(n))`. Then `g(n)` does dominate `f(n)`.

As this would be a very tricky question, I assume that you use the more common sloppy definition, which would give the answer C). (But you might want to check your definitions for `big-O`).

If my answer confuses you, then you probably didn't use the formal definition and you should probably ignore my answer...